# can we use spring boot and spring mvc 4 together

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

a small functionality of my app, is developed in spring boot, where as rest is developed in spring mvc. 
can i include the spring boot application as an external jar in my spring mvc application?
to be more precise, spring boot app is a filter, spring mvc is a regular hello world mvc. 
i would like to use filter as external jar in spring mvc. however when i do so the app, runs as a spring boot and not as spring mvc. it thorws autowire exception in  spring mvc application.

Comment: Including Spring boot's fat jar in another project is a bad idea. Why would you include a Spring boot project/JAR in another Spring project, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: i made an independent module, which is is on spring boot, i've to integrate with another person who did that in spring, so can i know if there is any possibility to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to create your own Spring Boot-based project is to visit [Spring Initializr](http://start.spring.io/), fill in your project details, pick your options, and then download either a Maven build file, or a bundled up project as a `zip` file.

---

Also here is an example of `pom.xml` file for Maven to start using Spring Boot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>your.groupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- then you can add any other Spring Boot dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: here is some more clarification, i already  have a jar with spring boot, now this has to be included in my spring application. i wanted to know how to include spring boot appliation jar in spring application.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225845/how-to-add-jar-files-for-spring-in-eclipse-ide-project-folder